# jquery select specific child

Tags: jquery

What is wrong with the below code. I am trying to loop over children of a specific id, and assigning a css class only to specific children.

```
var firstRC = $("#id_1").children();
    for(j=0;j<firstRC.length;j++) {
       if(j>5) {
        $("#id_1:eq(j)").addClass("cssClass");
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `j` in the jQuery selector is just a part of the string and not a variable. You'll need to create the selector string by concatenation:

```
var firstRC = $("#id_1").children();
  for(j=0;j<firstRC.length;j++) {
    if(j>5) {
      $("#id_1 :eq(" + j + ")").addClass("cssClass");
    }
  }
```

Also you need a space before `:eq`, or you'll select the j-th element with the id `id_1` and not the j-th child inside an element with `id_1`.

However you are doing it far to complicated. jQuery has a `gt` selector allowing you to select all elements ***g***reater ***t***han a specific index:

```
$("#id_1 :gt(5)").addClass("cssClass");
```

If you do need to loop over several elements you should ccheck out jQuery's `each` method, that is much <s>better</s> easier to use than a `for` loop. Inside the `each` loop, `this` refers to the current element.

Example:

```
$("#id_1").children().each(function(index) {
   if (index > 5)
      $(this).addClass("cssClass");
});
```

Comment: `much better` ? In terms of performance, a `for loop` is much better indeed: http://jsperf.com/for-loop-vs-each

Comment: True. If performance is an issue, I wouldn't recommend jQuery in the first place.

Comment: You can use jQuery even if performance really matters. Anyway, any `functional` loop is pretty slow compared to native `for` or `while` loops. I was just bothered by the relative statement `much better than (..)`

Comment: Ok, you win :-) I've change the sentence.

Comment: is it possible to select children between a range? something like gt(5) and lt(10)?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `j` variable is as a string. You need to bring it back into the JavaScript code.

```
var firstRC = $("#id_1").children();
for(j=0;j<firstRC.length;j++) {
   if(j>5) {
    $("#id_1:eq(" + j + ")").addClass("cssClass");
   }
}
```

Of course, if you're trying to set the class for everything greater than 5 you could do this:

```
$("#id_1 :gt(5)").addClass("cssClass");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/8sydw/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use a `:gt` selector or `.slice()` method to get the nodes you need.

```
$("#id_1").children().slice(5).addClass("cssClass");
```

ref.: [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)
example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/xDN9D/